# How to create side menu with react-native?

Tags: react-native, side-menu

I'm new in React Native, I want to create a side menu like this, any reference for this?

[image: side menu]

Answer (score 27, accepted):

I would like to say use reactnavigation. that is providing drawer
To open and close drawer, navigate to 'DrawerOpen' and 'DrawerClose' respectively.

```
 this.props.navigation.navigate('DrawerOpen'); // open drawer
    this.props.navigation.navigate('DrawerClose'); // close drawer
```

https://reactnavigation.org/docs/drawer-based-navigation.html

or here is one example That also is good . refer this

https://github.com/dailydrip/react-native-navigation-sample

Comment: What about using a library using npm?Is that approach suitable @Sport

Answer (score 11):

This is one of my simple project that may show you the idea how to implement a side menu by yourself.

https://github.com/reactazteam/PushyHorizontalMenu

[image]

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/16708197)

Comment: You're correct but here are the things.
1. The question owner asked about references.
2. This is in my github account and I'm not gonna change it.
3. It's kinda complicated to include all essential parts here also, so I just keep it simple.

Answer (score 4):

Here you can find a complete template ready to use.

https://github.com/darde/react-native-sidemenu